# basic calc: partial derivative of $f(x,y) = x + y$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

It has been many years since I had Calculus, and I am trying to brush up on some basics. I am told that if $f$ is defined as:

$$f(x,y)=x+y$$

then:

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$$

I expected it to be $1 + y$, because we hold $y$ constant when taking the derivative with respect to $x$.

Please explain how $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$.

Comment: You're right.. it isn't simply $1$

Comment: If you regard $y$ as constant, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y) = 0$, not $y$

Comment: @Ed_4434: Yes it is

Comment: @Ed_4434:  The partial with respect to $x$ certainly is $1$.  Since $y$ is treated as a constant, its rate of change with respect to $x$ is .... zero.

Comment: If $x$ is assumed as a constant you can write $f(x)=x+c$. Now differentiate w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Check out this link, it's a review of partial derivatives. Hope it helps...http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6ltHTltDMAhXkzIMKHdL3B7AQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.psu.edu%2Ftseng%2Fclass%2FMath251%2FNotes-Partial%2520Differentiation.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEvYxo8CV0wF6u0Nrsfs8WQ-QSTAg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of a constant is $0$. So, treating $y$ as a constant as you said should leave you with a final answer of $1$.

Comment: I get it. I was confused because previously, it was explained that for $f(x,y)=x \cdot y$, then: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y$.
The reason the y does not "drop out" in this case is because it's multiplied by the x. For $x+y$, the y is a separate term (a constant, as you pointed out). Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it! :-)